# MongoDB lookup and map 2 arrays of result

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

There are 2 array fields after I looked up in MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

the first one

```js
[
    {
        "colorId": "60828a1b216b0972da695f2a",
        "name": "Exellent",
        "description": "Great work"
    }
]
```

and the second one

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "60828a1b216b0972da695f2a",
        "colorName": "Green",
        "hexColorCodes": "#2D9D78",
        "sequence": 1,
        "isActivated": true,
        "created_at": "2021-04-23T08:49:31.729Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-04-23T08:49:31.729Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "isDefault": true
    }
]
```

the result I want is

```js
[
  {
    "colorId": "60828a1b216b0972da695f2a",
    "name": "Exellent",
    "description": "Great work",
    "colorName": "Green",
    "hexColorCodes": "#2D9D78"
  }
]
```

then I want to map `colorName` and `hexColorCodes` to the first array. Here is my aggregate pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
      $lookup: {
        from: "color_tags",
        localField: "colors.colorId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "tempColors",
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        stages3: {
          $map: {
            input: "$colors",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$this",
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$tempColors",
                    {
                      $indexOfArray: [
                        "$tempColors._id",
                        "$$this.colors.colorId",
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
])
```

but the result is not what I expected. It mapped with incorrect id. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `first` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `second` array and match `colorId` with `_id` and return matching result
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first matching element
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with return result from `second` array

```
  {
    $project: {
      first: {
        $map: {
          input: "$first",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$f",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$second",
                      cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$f.colorId"] }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you want to result specific fields then add a `$project` stage at the end,

```
  {
    $project: {
      "first.colorId": 1,
      "first.name": 1,
      "first.description": 1,
      "first.colorName": 1,
      "first.hexColorCodes": 1
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTMy3ClqgOr)